# Share variables in python between different docker containers

Tags: python, docker, ipc, shared-memory

I have a python app running in a docker container. In my app I'm caching some objects as their creation time is too big to have them created each time they're being used. I now want to spawn multiple containers of the same image to handle the possible load. The app is actually a webserver offering an API. However the cached objects would be the same for each of those containers so I was thinking if there maybe is some docker IPC or whatever functionality which allows me to store and use the same instances of these objects so I don't have any overhead in terms of copies of the same objects in memory. Is there any approach to realise that?

Comment: If you create the object before the processes fork, they will get a copy of the object in memory. Why is your object creation slow? Depending on your code it could be better to only cache the slow parts of object creation instead of the entire object itself. That will give you more options on how you can store a cache.

Comment: Object creation is slow because those objects are machine learning models where each can be up to a couple of hundred megabytes. The creation also needs to be on demand as I don't necessarilly need all possible objects.

Comment: Maybe you could pickle the objects and store in memcached

Comment: Docker won’t directly help you here, but it does make it straightforward to run a dedicated caching server (Redis, Memcached) alongside your other containers.

Comment: There is something new in Python 3.8 which might suit my need: [link](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) I'll try to setup a prototype and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The containers can all share the same volume mount. It's a lightweight way to share data between Docker containers.

For example, our "server" could simply append a number to a file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ID="$RANDOM"

while true ; do
    echo $ID >> /shared.txt
    sleep 1
done
```

Then we create a Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY main.sh /main.sh
CMD ["bash", "/main.sh"]
```

And a docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version:   '3'
services:
    one:
        build: ./
        volumes:
            - ./shared.txt:/shared.txt
    two:
        build: ./
        volumes:
            - ./shared.txt:/shared.txt
```

Notice how both containers are mounting the same file. They will each see the same thing.

Run it with `docker-compose up`, and in a separate window you'll see the following output of shared.txt:

```
25277
24626
25277
24626
25277
24626
25277
24626
25277
```

Both containers are able to write to the same file. You can easily extend this to directories so you can have multiple cached objects.